# What is the standard distance between a table and a banquette?

Tags: furniture, layout, planning

We just moved into a new condo that has a small area (43"x120") off the kitchen that I am thinking of converting to a dining nook with a narrow table. Considering the dimensions, it seems inappropriate to put chairs on the long side that is against the back wall, so I was thinking a banquette on 2 sides (one short, one long), to create a restaurant-style booth.

I have figured out the size of the banquette (18" wide seat, slightly angled with the back at 95° to the seat, giving me an approximate width of 22"), but to know how wide I can make the table, I need to figure out the proper spacing between a fixed banquette and a table. What is the standard for that?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard... the correct distance for you will depend on your size and your ability to slide along that 8' seat.  Also, it's your property, so you should put your furniture where you like.

Answer (score 1):

My interior decorator recommended about 1 meter. Also, a good tip is to put newspaper on the floor where you're thinking to put your furniture to get a better visual effect. Get the newspaper on the floor in the right position and then measure.